# ASP.NET User control Eval() DB.Null problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control that contains a repeater. The repeater outputs either one or two columns based on the parameters used when an instance of it is created.

If a value is not specified for the second column i.e only one column should be displayed, it doesn't seem to like it if a value hasn't been set.

I'm trying to output a string that is set in the user control code behind, not a data item.

I have the following aspx:

```
<%# Eval(Column2Data) == DBNull.Value ? "</tr> " : String.Format("<td>{0}</td></tr>", Eval(Column2Data))%>
```

If `Column2Data` has a value, it works but if it doesn't the following error is displayed:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: expression
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
<% (Column2Data == null) ? "</tr>td></td></tr>", Eval(Column2Data))%>
```

If value is null I think you want to present empty td

Comment: Thanks for your reply - but it didn't work, I get the same error or if I  use the exact code you gave it gives a compilation error.

Comment: Yes, but it still displays an error because Column2Data has not been set. It works when data has been set for Column2Data but when it's null or hasn't had any data set, it displays an error.

Comment: when you do debug what you see is the value of Column2Data

Comment: Can you send me the full code block that related to this issue

Comment: Column2Data is a string of an item value from a data source record. It errors if you try and check String.IsNullOrEmpty() and it errors if you use DBNull.Value. The only way around it is to set it with an empty string.

Comment: Yes you need to assing with the String.empty

Comment: I used the following and it worked: <%#  String.IsNullOrEmpty(Column2Data) ? "</tr> " : String.Format("<td>{0}</td></tr>", Eval(Column2Data))%>

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're looking for:

```
<%#  DBNull.Value.Equals(Eval(Column2Data)) ? "</tr> " : String.Format("<td>{0}</td></tr>", Eval(Column2Data))%>
```

Comment: I get the error 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: expression'. I think it's because I'm trying output a string that's set in the user control code behind and not a data item - which is probably why DBNULL.Value doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 <%# Eval("Column2Data")==null  ? "<tr><td>N.A</td></tr>" 
                 : Eval("Column2Data","<tr><td>{0}</td></tr>")%>
```

This is the sample List,

```
public class Data
    {
        public int? Column2Data { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            List<Data> list = new List<Data>()
            {
                 new Data(){ Column2Data=10100},
                 new Data(){},
                 new Data(){ Column2Data=4000}
            };
            Repeater1.DataSource = list;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that should work, but it doesn't because I get an error: does not contain a property with the name 'Column2Data'. I think this is because I'm not trying to output a data item, I'm trying to output a string that is set in the user control code behind.

Comment: @aspdotnetuse - Eval() expression must be embed with single or double quotes. Please verify the DataSource. Which kind of data source you are using? - DataSet/Collection.

Comment: The datasource is an IEnumberable collection of objects. It displays the items ok because they're data items and can be output using Eval("DataItemName"). But how do you check for null or empty string using Eval()? It doesn't like it if a string attribute (not a data item) is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
<%# (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Eval("Column2Data")))) ? "Value" :Eval("Column2Data") %>
```